# Iterating over an array that point to other arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to iterate over an array that includes pointers to other arrays.

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t upperLimit, lowerLimit;
} Poi;

Poi poi_new(uint8_t upperLimit, uint8_t lowerLimit) {
  Poi i;
  i.upperLimit = upperLimit;
  i.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
  return i;
}

Poi lox1_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90) };
Poi lox2_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50) };
Poi lox3_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50) };
Poi lox4_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90) };

Poi * pois[] = { lox1_POI , lox2_POI , lox3_POI , lox4_POI };
```

At this point how do I iterate over `pois` and then iterate over whatever array it points to?

I have started with the code below, but I am getting lost getting the syntax correct:

```
for (int c = 0; c++; c < sizeof(*pois[i])) {
    //... now to iterate over the internal lists
}
```

Comment: `for (int c = 0; c++; c < sizeof(*pois[i]))` <-- it is **invalid**

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych, that part  is compiling fine

Comment: I'm aboul *logic*: in your `for` loop your condition is `c++` (basically overflow leading lo UB because of signed int) and increment is `c < sizeof(*pois[i])` that does nothing. Take a look at @Someprogrammerdude 's answer

Comment: poi_new(uint8_t,uint8_t) is returning a local structure!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sentinel: i.e `{0, 0}` in order to know when to stop iterating:

```
Poi lox1_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90), {0, 0} };
Poi lox2_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), {0, 0} };
Poi lox3_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), {0, 0} };
Poi lox4_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90), {0, 0} };

Poi *pois[] = { lox1_POI , lox2_POI , lox3_POI , lox4_POI };
Poi *ptr;

for (int c = 0; c < sizeof(pois) / sizeof(pois[0]); c++) {  /* Note condition in the middle */
    printf("%d)\n", c);
    //... now to iterate over the internal lists
    ptr = pois[c];
    while ((ptr->upperLimit != 0) && (ptr->lowerLimit != 0)) {
        printf("\t%d %d\n", ptr->upperLimit, ptr->lowerLimit);
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

Or you can create a table containing those elements and his sizes:

```
Poi lox1_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90) };
Poi lox2_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50) };
Poi lox3_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50) };
Poi lox4_POI[] = { poi_new(40,50), poi_new(60,70) , poi_new(80,90) };

struct poi_table {
    Poi *elem;
    size_t elems;   
} table[] = {
    { lox1_POI, sizeof(lox1_POI) / sizeof(lox1_POI[0]) },
    { lox2_POI, sizeof(lox2_POI) / sizeof(lox2_POI[0]) },
    { lox3_POI, sizeof(lox3_POI) / sizeof(lox3_POI[0]) },
    { lox4_POI, sizeof(lox4_POI) / sizeof(lox4_POI[0]) }
};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]); i++) {
    printf("%d)\n", i);
    //... now to iterate over the internal lists
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].elems; j++) {
        printf("\t%d %d\n", table[i].elem[j].upperLimit, table[i].elem[j].lowerLimit);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0)
    40 50
    60 70
    80 90
1)
    40 50
2)
    40 50
3)
    40 50
    60 70
    80 90
```

Answer (score 1):

To normally get the number of elements in an array, you divide the size of the array (e.g. `sizeof pois`) with the size of a single element (e.g. `sizeof pois[0]`).

Note that this only works with an actual arrays, if you pass the array to a function it will have decayed to a pointer to the arrays first element, and the `sizeof` operator will return the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

And to be technically correct, remember that the type of a `sizeof` expression is a `size_t`, so the iterator variable (`c` in your example) should be a `size_t` variable.

Lastly, you have a very basic problem in the *order* of the expressions in the `for` statement. A `for` statement is `for (init; condition; increment)`. You have switched `condition` and `increment`.

---

Putting it all together, to iterate over `pois` you do

```
for (size_t c = 0; c < sizeof pois / sizeof pois[0]; ++c)
{
    // Here you can use `pois[c]`
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am really not getting the code above! Is that really the right syntax?

Comment: @theAlse No, because I forgot to define `c`. Fixed now.

Comment: @thanks, I got that but I wanted to iterate over what pois[c] is pointing to so to say

Comment: @theAlse That is harder, not to say impossible the way you currently have it set up. A simple solution is to put in an "end of the array" marker (for example a `Poi` whose values are really invalid) at the end of the arrays, and then iterate over them until you find the special marker. Another also simple solution is to have a *second* top-level array, lets say `pois_sizes`, which contains the number of elements in each array pointed to by `pois`. So to get the number of elements of `pois[c]` you use `pois_sizes[c]`.